# Parse JS conflict with Angular JS when query - Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have a `Ionic` app with a simple angular controller, a service and a view that is a list of items.

When I use a list of POJOs as data, it works ok. But when I add a Parse query `find` there happends the error:

```
20    319061   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29033:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14945:9
invoke@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14943:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14857:5
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41671:5
trigger@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16308:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:9

21    319062   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js, Line: 13380
```

even when the data is never used, just made the call. It's like Parse is connected in some way to the Angular internals, but I can't figure out how.

Execution steps:

1. Loads app
2. The router config sends to `/list`
3. Calls **DataService.getBuildings()**  to resolve the parameter for the controller
4. If there is no call to Parse SDK inside **getBuildings()** no problem
5. If there is a call to Parse SDK then the resolve is called again until there is an error for recursion.

Angular JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // Set the statusbar to use the default style, tweak this to
      // remove the status bar on iOS or change it to use white instead of dark colors.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    Parse.initialize("KEY","VALUE"); // Parse credentials (with correct values in the real code)

  });
});

app.service('DataService', function($q) {
  return {
    buildingsI: [ // hardcoded data
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Colectivo',
    state_id: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Otro',
    state_id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Mas',
    state_id: 2
      }
    ]
    ,
    _getData: function() {

      console.log('_getData()');

      var defer = $q.defer();

      var BuildingObject = Parse.Object.extend("Building");
      Object.defineProperty(BuildingObject.prototype,"id",{
             get: function() {
            return this.get('id');
         },
         set: function(aval) {
            this.set('id',aval);
         }
      });
      Object.defineProperty(BuildingObject.prototype,"name",{
             get: function() {
            return this.get('name');
         },
         set: function(aval) {
            this.set('name',aval);
         }
      });

      var query = new Parse.Query(BuildingObject);
      query.include("state");
      query.limit(1000);
      query.ascending("name");
       console.log('Before find');
           query.find().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                defer.resolve(data);
                             },
                             function (error) {
                defer.reject(error);
                             });
       console.log('After find');

       return defer.promise; 
    },

    getBuildings: function() {

        console.log('Call getBuildings(), begins getData');

        this._getData();// Here is the call that launchs Parse query, I don't use the data

        console.log('Ends getData');

        return this.buildingsI; // List of hardcoded data, the idea is to replace this with Parse data
    }
  }
});


app.controller('BuildingsCtrl', ['$scope','buildings',
   function($scope, buildingsP) {
       console.log('Call BuildingsCtrl constructor');
       console.log(buildingsP.length);
       this.buildings = buildingsP;
   }
]);



app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('list', {
    url: '/list',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: 'BuildingsCtrl as myCtrl',
    resolve: {
      buildings: function($stateParams, DataService) {
        console.log('Call dataService');
        return DataService.getBuildings();
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/list");
});
```

If I remove the internal call to `_getData()`  the app renders the hardcoded data. If I left the internal call, it reaches the call to `query.find(...)` , never call `success` function and start to begin the call again from the data service. Later it throws the error a couple of times, with some differences (see below).

Versions:

> **Ionic** 1.2.4
>
> **Parse SDK** 1.6.14

I'm not using any kind of specific Angular-Parse plugin.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here is error stack with traces:

```
ionic $ restart
Loading: /?restart=475324
ionic $ 0     531257   log      Call dataService
1     531258   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
2     531258   log      _getData()
3     531262   log      Before find
4     531275   log      Call dataService
5     531277   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
6     531279   log      _getData()
7     531279   log      Before find
8     531292   log      Call dataService
9     531292   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
10    531293   log      _getData()
11    531295   log      Before find
12    531344   log      Call dataService
13    531346   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
14    531347   log      _getData()
15    531348   log      Before find
16    531364   log      Call dataService
17    531366   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
18    531369   log      _getData()
19    531371   log      Before find
20    531376   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29033:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14945:9
invoke@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14943:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14857:5
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41671:5
trigger@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16308:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:9

21    531379   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js, Line: 13380
22    531481   log      Call dataService
23    531497   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
24    531498   log      _getData()
25    531500   log      Before find
26    531505   log      After find
27    531506   log      Ends getData
28    531529   log      Call BuildingsCtrl constructor
29    531530   log      11
30    531727   error    too much recursion, http://localhost:8100/js/parse-1.6.14.js, Line: 3319
0     532183   log      Call dataService
1     532183   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
2     532184   log      _getData()
3     532186   log      Before find
4     532195   log      Call dataService
6     532198   log      _getData()
5     532197   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
7     532199   log      Before find
8     532206   log      Call dataService
9     532236   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
10    532237   log      _getData()
11    532238   log      Before find
12    532254   log      Call dataService
13    532256   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
14    532258   log      _getData()
15    532261   log      Before find
16    532269   log      Call dataService
17    532271   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
20    532275   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29033:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14945:9
invoke@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14943:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14857:5
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41671:5
trigger@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16308:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:9

18    532272   log      _getData()
19    532273   log      Before find
21    532276   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js, Line: 13380
22    532318   log      Call dataService
23    532320   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
24    532322   log      _getData()
25    532325   log      Before find
26    532332   log      After find
27    532334   log      Ends getData
28    532357   log      Call BuildingsCtrl constructor
29    532360   log      11
0     532570   log      Call dataService
1     532571   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
2     532573   log      _getData()
3     532577   log      Before find
4     532640   log      Call dataService
5     532641   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
6     532643   log      _getData()
7     532644   log      Before find
8     532716   log      Call dataService
9     532717   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
10    532718   log      _getData()
11    532719   log      Before find
12    532728   log      Call dataService
14    532729   log      _getData()
13    532728   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
16    532738   log      Call dataService
15    532730   log      Before find
18    532740   log      _getData()
17    532739   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
19    532741   log      Before find
20    532746   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29033:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14945:9
invoke@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14943:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14857:5
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41671:5
trigger@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16308:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:9

21    532747   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js, Line: 13380
30    532775   error    too much recursion, http://localhost:8100/js/parse-1.6.14.js, Line: 3319
22    532786   log      Call dataService
23    532786   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
24    532787   log      _getData()
25    532788   log      Before find
26    532798   log      After find
27    532799   log      Ends getData
28    532817   log      Call BuildingsCtrl constructor
29    532818   log      11
0     533004   log      Call dataService
1     533005   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
2     533006   log      _getData()
3     533008   log      Before find
4     533017   log      Call dataService
6     533018   log      _getData()
5     533018   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
7     533019   log      Before find
8     533028   log      Call dataService
9     533033   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
10    533034   log      _getData()
11    533036   log      Before find
12    533046   log      Call dataService
13    533048   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
14    533048   log      _getData()
15    533050   log      Before find
16    533060   log      Call dataService
17    533069   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
20    533074   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29033:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14945:9
invoke@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14943:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14857:5
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41671:5
trigger@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16308:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:9

21    533075   error    Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js, Line: 13380
18    533069   log      _getData()
19    533070   log      Before find
22    533153   log      Call dataService
23    533155   log      Call getBuildings(), begins getData
24    533155   log      _getData()
25    533156   log      Before find
27    533163   log      Ends getData
26    533162   log      After find
28    533179   log      Call BuildingsCtrl constructor
29    533180   log      11
30    533220   error    too much recursion, http://localhost:8100/js/parse-1.6.14.js, Line: 3319
30    533391   error    too much recursion, http://localhost:8100/js/parse-1.6.14.js, Line: 3319
```

Comment: does your `"state"` that you are including have `"buildings"`?  Try removing the `query.include("state")` and see if it still throws recursion errors.  BTW, it's not just angular throwing errors, there are multiple `too much recursion` errors from parse, which seems to indicate that buildings is finding states, which is finding more buildings, which is finding more states, indefinitely.

Comment: i am not sure if this is the answer thats why i am adding it as a comment, i assume it has to do with the $apply. Try changing it to $applyAsync();

Comment: @Claies thanks. Removed the `query.include("state")` but still fails. I think the problem is related with the internal cycle of  `apply` -> `digest` of `angular`. But I don't see how the `Parse` call relates to it.

Comment: @Akis_Tfs thanks. I never do an explicit call to `$apply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this section

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // Set the statusbar to use the default style, tweak this to
      // remove the status bar on iOS or change it to use white instead of dark colors.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    Parse.initialize("KEY","VALUE"); // Parse credentials (with correct values in the real code)

  });
});
```

The call `$ionicPlatform.ready` is executed after the view is rendered, and the initialization of `Parse` was inside.

So, when the view render was executed `DataService.getBuildings()` was called, inside this is `query.find()` that throws a Parse exception because it was no initialized (`$ionicPlatform.ready` is executed after). Because this occurs on Angular `$digest` every time the digest cycle receives an error the `$digest` is executed again trying to converge to a correct state, and the times the `$digest` cycle is executed is limited to 10 times. That's what appears on the error log, but not the Parse exception.

The solution was to execute the initialization before `$ionicPlatform.ready` :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

  Parse.initialize("KEY","VALUE");// MOVED OUT OF 'ready'

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // Set the statusbar to use the default style, tweak this to
      // remove the status bar on iOS or change it to use white instead of dark colors.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
```